# How to set the frame of one view inside the main view?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a UIView inside the main screen which contains 3 imageviews. My intention to display one image at a time. Whenever the user clicks arrow button placed right and left of the view, i want to move the image views. I tried the following code to display one image.
 **in ViewController.h**

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) UIView *view1;
```

**in ViewController.m**

```
self.view1.frame = CGRectMake(20,100,100,100);
[self.view addSubView:view1]
```

But it displays all the images.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you used a scrollview to display one imageview  at a time.

Here is a nice tutorial to do the same.

http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/

Answer (score 0):

You can Take only one image view and Change The images on Button Click. You can take a Integer (i) for increasing and decreasing The Value. And An image Array which will Contain all Image Names(imageArray).

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
i++;

if(i<[imageArray count])
{
imageView.Image =[UIImage imagenamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[ImageArray ObjectAtindex:i]];
}
 else
{i=0;
imageView.Image =[UIImage imagenamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[ImageArray ObjectAtindex:i]];

}


}

-(IBAction)previous:(id)sender
{
i--
if(i>0)
{
imageView.Image =[UIImage imagenamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[ImageArray ObjectAtindex:i]];
}
 else
{i=[imageArray Count];
imageView.Image =[UIImage imagenamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",[ImageArray ObjectAtindex:i]];

}
```

}